# jQuery Accordion with YouTube/Soundcloud embed

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, accordion, soundcloud

Currently I'm working on a page for upcoming releases (music). Each release has it's own YouTube or Soundcloud embedded preview. I would like to place these embeds in accordion panels with automatic start/stop.

**The idea:**

The accordion content will slide down and the YouTube OR Soundcloud embedded player will be loaded after clicking on the accordion title. The embedded player will also autoplay once it's loaded. The embedded player will automatically stop if you open another accordion (track).

I really don't know how to do make this with jQuery. Hope you guys can help me!

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Preview URL:** http://dev.wbrnd.nl/hardnews/muziek/

**HTML:**

```
<dl class="accordion">
    <dt><span>Artist - Title - Label - Cat. ID</span><i class="accordion_icon fa fa-play"></i></dt>
    <dd class="accordion_content">
        YouTube player 1
    </dd>
    <dt><span>Artist - Title - Label - Cat. ID</span><i class="accordion_icon fa fa-play"></i></dt>
    <dd class="accordion_content">
        Soundcloud player 1
    </dd>
    <dt><span>Artist - Title - Label - Cat. ID</span><i class="accordion_icon fa fa-play"></i></dt>
    <dd class="accordion_content">
        YouTube Player 2
    </dd>
    <dt><span>Artist - Title - Label - Cat. ID</span><i class="accordion_icon fa fa-play"></i></dt>
    <dd class="accordion_content">
        Soundcloud player 2
    </dd>
</dl>
```

**Javascript:**

```
jQuery(".accordion dt").click(function() {
jQuery(this).toggleClass("active").find("i").toggleClass("fa-play fa-stop")
            .closest("dt").siblings("dt")
            .removeClass("active").find("i").removeClass("fa-stop").addClass("fa-play");

            jQuery(this).next(".accordion_content").stop().slideToggle().siblings(".accordion_content").slideUp();

            jQuery(this).next(".youtube").hide();
});

jQuery(".accordion_content").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load the content of each tab dynamically after the activate event is called. You can get the index of the active item by using:

```
accordion("option", "active");
```

Then you can set the html attribute of the actual panel to a youtube or soundcloud code with the autoplay attribute enabled.

```
$('.accordion').accordion({ 
activate: function(event, ui){
    var aindex= $( ".accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active" );
    $(".accordion dd").eq(aindex).html("Youtube/Soundcloud Code with autoplay here...");
}
});
```

I tested the above on my page with an accordion and changed stuff to fit yours but you may need to tweak it a bit to work for you.

You will need to set the inactive tabs default value first as well to remove other videos. Do this in the beginning of activate function.

for example:

```
$('.accordion').accordion({ 
activate: function(event, ui){
    $(".accordion dd").each(function() {
      $( this ).text("Loading...");
    });
    var aindex= $( ".accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active" );
    $(".accordion dd").eq(aindex).html("Youtube/Soundcloud Code with autoplay here...");
}
});
```

You could even store the codes for each youtube or soundcloud in an array and use the aindex variable to pull up the correct value.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Could you make a fiddle of this :-)?

Comment: I tweaked the "loading..." line and added a simple sc player embed code to it as well. Please note that you must escape the code if you're going to use it as a static js variable.
https://jsfiddle.net/3zqv55fL/3/

Comment: If this answers your question, please make sure to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks Stellar! We are almost there. I have 3 questions: 1: I tried the code with Youtube, but the player is hiding after opening. Do you have a solution for that? 2: Is it possible to grab the ID (in the HTML: id="[YT TRACK ID]") and play that one? 3: something is going wrong when I open the second item. There is a track playing in the background, but all the panels are closed. Hope you can help me with this :-). I updates the fiddle for my needs: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3zqv55fL/6)

Comment: I think you're trolling for someone to write your code for you. Here's my last hint : http://jsfiddle.net/3zqv55fL/7/ It would be more effective if you asked for help politely on the side and I would be more than glad to help you.